# How can I implement GDPR in a simple program?

Tags: gdpr, european-union, eula

I would like to get some analytics from a simple program that I wrote to manage a game server.

The data I want are (collected every 15 min):

- operative system (windows/linux 32/64bit)
- machine id (transformed via sha256 to maintain anonymity)
- time when the program was launched
- version of the program
- number of players on the server

If needed I can let the user decide if he/she wants to send the data or not.

The server for data collection would be, for the majority of time, offline and I would start it once a week for few hours to get some usage info.

the data would not be shared to anyone (obvously... it's something nobody would care about (except for me since I spent hundreds of hours to write the program))

Are there any license agreements pre made for such simple usage? Should I write one? What steps should I take to protect myself and reassure the users?

What would change in the license if, instead of sending these data, I just made the program connect every 15 min (without sending anything), just to signal that 1 client is using the program?

Comment: The only thing that might count as GDPR-protected data here is the 'machine ID'. What is this ID? Do you mean an IP address? Or some random GUID that is generated and then matched based on IP address or something?

Comment: no it's a 32 byte code that it's used to identify the hardware of the machine (since i don't have the names/ip of users)... i cannot identify the hardware from this code. (as a plus i'm using sha256 before sending it to my server collector)

Comment: i have in any case to declare it in a document and let the users decide right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get this certain, the operating system and machine ID are those of **your** server, where players "are" by having a session or the like? And the only thing you know about your players is how many there are, in total?

Then it sounds as if your **monitoring** does not process PII of your users.

That being said, operating a server where players can log in and maintain their session will involve other data which may be PII.

So you are better off talking to an expert, even if that costs some money.